# Scrapy - Use feed exporter for a particular spider (and not others) in a project

Tags: python, json, scrapy

ENVIRONMENT:
Windows7, Python 3.6.5, Scrapy 1.5.1

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:

I have a scrapy project called `project_github`, which contains 3 spiders:`spider1`, `spider2`, `spider3`. Each of these spiders scrapes data from a particular website individual to that spider.

I am trying to automatically export a JSON file when a particular spider is executed, with the format: `NameOfSpider_TodaysDate.json`, so that from the command line I can:

Execute the script `scrapy crawl spider1` which returns `spider1_181115.json`

Currently I am using `ITEM EXPORTERS` in `settings.py` with the following code:

```
import datetime
FEED_URI = 'spider1_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d') + '.json'
FEED_FORMAT = 'json'
FEED_EXPORTERS = {'json': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonItemExporter'}
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Obviously this code always writes `spider1_TodaysDate.json` regardless of the spider used... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to do this is by defining `custom_settings` as a `class` attribute under the specific spider were are writing the item exporter for. Spider settings override project settings.

So, for `spider1`:

```
class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    allowed_domains = []

    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'spider1_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d') + '.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {
            'json': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonItemExporter',
        },
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
    }
```

Comment: just today I had an issue with printing date and used the way you do until I figured out the shorter way via  `str(datetime.date.today())`