# Scrapy 2.5 - How do I associate my spiders with a specific feed export?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

How do I link a specific Spider with a specific Feed Export?

I currently have two spiders spider1 and spider2. I added the FEEDS dict to settings.py but am not sure how to associate the individual spiders to an individual feed URI / export.

I would use custom settings as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318905/scrapy-use-feed-exporter-for-a-particular-spider-and-not-others-in-a-project), but this method is deprecated in use of FEEDS.

Settings for FEEDS

```
FEEDS = {
    'csv/<exportfilename-spider1>.csv':{
        'format': 'csv',
        'overwrite': True
    },
    'csv/<exportfilename-spider2>.csv':{
        'format': 'csv',
        'overwrite': True
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the custom_settings in each individual spider. Please let me know if there is a better solution.

In yourSpiderName.py add:

```
    custom_settings= {
        'FEEDS': {
            'csv/<filename>.csv':{
                'format': 'csv',
                'overwrite': True
            }
        }
```